# Making a count for 'Others' outside of top 5 results with Pig

Tags: apache-pig

So I have hundreds of groups being generated and am trying to avoid having to sift through them and only look at those with the most results. For this I am counting them, ordering them and then limiting to top 5 results.

```
counts = foreach (group distinctVals by (description)) generate group, COUNT_STAR(distinctVals) as count;
ordered = order counts by count desc;
limited = limit ordered 5;
dump limited;
```

However I would like to have a separate count of how many results did not make the "top 5" and bin them as a group simply called other.

So my output would be something like

```
(John ,38436)
(Steve ,13654)
(Sarah ,9334)
(Rick ,3241)
(Morty ,784)
(Other ,3421)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RANK](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#rank). After ordering the data,use `RANK` to generate a rank for ordered relation.This will add a new rank_ordered column as the first column.You can then use the rank column to `FILTER` the dataset into two relations say  limited,other.Once you have the other relation,`GROUP ALL` and `SUM` the 3rd column i.e.$2 or count column.Finally, `UNION` limited and the other_sum.

```
counts = foreach (group distinctVals by (description)) generate group, COUNT_STAR(distinctVals) as count;
ordered = order counts by count desc;
ordered1 = rank ordered;

limited = FILTER ordered1 BY rank_ordered <= 5;
other = FILTER ordered1 BY rank_ordered > 5;

other_grp = GROUP other ALL;
other_sum = FOREACH other_grp GENERATE SUM(other.$2);

final = UNION limited,other_sum;
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill give it a go.